# Salesforce DEs are not visible in Automation Studio when configuring an Email Send

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, automationstudio, send-email

Does anyone know what happened to Salesforce Data Extensions in Automation Studio Email Sends?

We can't find it... I've looked at a few client accounts and it seems to have disappeared?  For existing automations that use a SF DE, those DEs are still visible but we can't change them because there's no SF DE folder visible.

[image: automation studio DE selection]

Did we miss something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They should still be available as their own activity called Salesforce Email Send. You might need to get that enabled in your account because I see it in some accounts but not others.

[image: Salesforce Email Send]

Answer (score 1):

This comes standard with Marketing Cloud Connect, but you need to be logged in as an integrated user to see this.

In other words, there needs to be a "user level connection" together with the "account level connection" that the connector sets up by default, so that the sendout can be attributed to an owner. Typically, when following the instructions to set up MC Connect, towards the end you integrate the API user. So when you are logged in as that, you should see it. If more people need to see the icon, integrate them as well (if you have the licenses to do so).

Answer (score 0):

When creating a Email Send activity in Journey Builder, the Salesforce Data Extensions folder and Shared Salesforce Data Extensions folder will never be present.

This is functioning as designed.

You would need to create a Salesforce Send definition via the Interactions tab in Email Studio and then use the Salesforce Email Send tile in Automation Studio, where you can select the newly created Salesforce Send definition.